# Why does my deffered() function not work unless I reference it thourgh another variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myFunc = function() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  //Do some code...
  //That might have ajax calls
  dfd.resolve(); // Resovle deferred
  return dfd.promise(); //Return the promise
}
```

This gives an error .done is not a function

```
myFunc.done(function(){
  console.log("ALL DONE...");
});
```

However, if I first do this:

```
var ref = myFunc();

ref.done(function(){
  console.log("ALL DONE...");
});
```

Now everything works just fine, I don't understand why the reference in btween the two functions is needed?

Comment: change to `myFunc().done` - you execute different code in these two cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is attempting to invoke a `done` function on the `myFunc` object itself:

```
myFunc.done(function(){
  console.log("ALL DONE...");
});
```

You need to actually call the function to get hold of the promise:

```
myFunc().done(function(){
  console.log("ALL DONE...");
});
```

Which you've done when you assign it to a variable:

```
var ref = myFunc();
```

Had this line been:

```
var ref = myFunc;
```

You would get the same error.

Comment: Oh my god, talk about not seeing the forest for the trees. So obvious now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
myFunc().done(function(){
  console.log("ALL DONE...");
});
```

You have to invoke `myFunc`.